# How would one go about creating a very simplistic online mixer?

Tags: javascript, html

**The requirements -**
Suppose there is a song with 4 tracks. Let's say guitar, bass, rhythm and vocals. And you want to give the user an option to mute/unmute any one or more of these tracks during the course of the song.

**How would you go about creating this simplistic mixer (kinda thing) on a browser? Javascript/jQuery?**

Additional information -
The 4 tracks will be available as separate audio files of equal duration each.

Answer (score 3):

There is some good info here regarding changing the volume of an audio tag with JavaScript, maybe it will help:

http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/introduction-to-the-html5-audio-tag-javascript-manipulation/

I guess the idea is that you set the volume of the track to zero when the mute button is clicked. And set it back to the original when it is clicked again

Comment: And do you think I can play all these tracks simultaneously, so that they are synchronised?

Comment: @Sussagittikasusa: I have not really used the audio tag so I am not sure how well they sync up if you play them all at the same time. I imagine it will be tricky as some may download data slower and hit a buffer while others still play. You will have to have a play and see what happens. I think if you get something simple working you can come back later and ask another question regarding syncing and then you can show some of your code for better help.